# Bootstrap 5: slider / carousel products

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I try create slider / carousel products like this below screen using Bootstrap5:

[image]

Here I paste, This is my current code:

```css
<style>
<!-- Temporary -->
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background: black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Home Section End -->
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <div class="row g-4">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-4 ratio_medium d-sm-block d-none"> 
      <div class="home-section bg-white div-content" style="height:236px;">
    <!-- With Captions -->
<div id="carouselExampleCaption" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">          
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaption" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaption" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 ratio_65 d-xl-block d-none">
          <div class="home-section bg-white div-content" style="height:236px;">
    <!-- With Captions -->
<div id="carouselExampleCaption2" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/elegant-watch-with-silver-golden-chain-isolated_181624-27080.jpg?w=740&t=st=1674127568~exp=1674128168~hmac=5ce04dff715884c11a1cddc3e0a50b7c625fedf703c03ed40824dd972da0f012" style="width:20%;" alt="" class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto">          
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaption2" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaption2" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Home Section End -->
```

But currently this look like bad:
[image]

Display only one item, but I need display like this 3 items and half.  Also I try add under photo price and product title and image must be responsive. Can anyone little help me correct this code?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to search for this you can find [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/LYORMQW) and [this Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/jCzaESNi07).

##### Combining the two gives you a working example here (Codepen).

The JS clones the content of each `.carousel-item`, so each `.carousel-item` will hold the content of its (5) siblings. The CSS changes the `transform` so the slider moves accordingly.

It's also responsive by only showing one item before the smallest breakpoint, but this can be easily adjusted (CSS only).

Here it is in a snippet, **view it in full screen using the "Full page" link:**

*Note: had to add a bunch of `!important` in the CSS which is not needed if you load your CSS after Bootstrap's, like in the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/raequan-averie/pen/NWBwZOJ).*

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const minPerSlide = 5
  let next = el.nextElementSibling
  for (var i = 1; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    if (!next) {
      // wrap carousel by using first child
      next = items[0]
    }
    let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
    el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
    next = next.nextElementSibling
  }
})
```

```css
.carousel-item .col {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div:first-child {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex !important;
}


/* medium and up screens */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(20%) !important;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-20%) !important;
  }
  /*  half slides CSS */
  .carousel-inner:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 85%;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .carousel-inner:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 85%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .carousel-control-prev {
    left: 12% !important;
  }
  .carousel-control-next {
    right: 12% !important;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start {
  transform: translateX(0) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel carousel-dark slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/CB997E/333333?text=1" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/DDBEA9/333333?text=2" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/FFE8D6/333333?text=3" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/B7B7A4/333333?text=4" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/A5A58D/333333?text=5" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/6B705C/eeeeee?text=6" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying to make this code also to work on extra large screens, so 1200px one. But im having problems with it :(